# Connect Two Tables With Different Column Names

Tags: entity-framework

I have two database views, Customer and CustomerOrder. I am only allowed to use the views and not the database tables. I don't really need the tables because I only read data. Each CustomerOrder has a corresponding Customer.

Here is my code:

```
    namespace store.Models
    {
        public class CustomerOrderModel
        {
            [Key]
            public String orderNumber { get; set; }
            public String billingCustomerID { get; set; }
            public String poNumber { get; set; }
        }

        public class CustomerModel
        {
            [Key]
            public String customerID { get; set; }
            public String name { get; set; }
            public String address { get; set; }
        }

        public class StoreContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<CustomerOrderModel> CustomerOrders { get; set; }
            public DbSet<CustomerModel> Customers { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

How do I connect CustomerOrder and Customer (CustomerOrder.billingCustomerID = Customer.customerID)?

I have seen a lot of questions about this, but most of them connect foreign keys and have the same column names for both tables. I do not have the option to change any of the column names.

Comment: Have you looked into ForeignKeyAttribute? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would create a view model for this that had the fields that you wanted to send to the view.  then on your controller populate the view model from the different tables

```
var data1 = //populate first table
var data2 = //populate second table
List<Model> table = new List<Model>();
foreach(var temp in data1){
    Model model = new Model();
    data2select = data2.Where(x => x.CustomerID = temp.billingCustomerID);
    model.ID = temp.id;
    model.address = data2select.address;
    etc
    table.add(model);
}
```

Edit:

if you only want a single column you should probably just create a List instead of a model to make it simpler

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
```

and in the foreach

```
list.add(temp.name);  //the field that you want 
list.add(data2select.name);
```

Comment: What if I only want a single row (customer order)?

Comment: for a single row I would just define a list of string and add to it,  see my edit